# Flex DataType Conversion

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, casting

I have a very simple question regarding the type conversion in flex.

What is the difference between these two conversions.

1) var arrCol:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(event.result.dataset.table);

2) var arrCol:ArrayCollection = event.result.dataset.table as ArrayCollection;

I have seen that the second conversion works better(more number of times) than the first one.

Answer (score 5):

I think the term "conversion" isn't correct. In your code snippets there are present instantiating and casting.

The case 1) is instantiating (creating of new instance of class). To determine it take a look at `new` keyword. And the parameter is `Array` instance according to [`ArrayCollection`'s constructor documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html#ArrayCollection%28%29).

The case 2) is casting. In your case `event.result.dataset.table` should be an `ArrayCollection`. Otherwise the value of `arrCol` will be `null`. Another form of casting is:

```
var arrCol:ArrayCollection = ArrayCollection (event.result.dataset.table);
```

In this case if `event.result.dataset.table` isn't an `ArrayCollection` there will be runtime exception. Because of `Array` and `ArrayCollection` are incompatible types and can't cast them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

`event.result.dataset.table as ArrayCollection` is more readable and faster to write. But I remember some situation where flex threw an error when object was converted this way.